# Make an app open on typing the name in run command

Tags: windows, environment-variables, shortcut

I want to open certain folders and files using run command.

I know that creating a shortcut for the required file or folder and placing it in the System32 folder will do the task. However i don't like to use System32 folder.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a folder under local hard disk and put the shortcuts into that and i would route it some how such that i would be able to open the apps and the files directly by typing the name of the shortcut into the run window.

Setting any Environment Variables would help?

Comment: Sure that's possible. Just add that folder to your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the folder to the **PATH** variable solved the issue.
As correctly answered by  **a_horse_with_no_name**.